# Auto layout is locked on Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, autolayout

When I pressed to enable Auto Layout in Interface Builder picklock is shown on screen.
My question is what can be cause of this issue? I am using Storyboard scenes with Container View Controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to "`Reset Locking Controls`" in the `Editor > Localization Locking` menu (don't forget to first select the storyboard on the left bar) :

[image: Editor > Localization Locking > Reset Locking Controls]

Then try re-activating autolayout.